# Combine 2 MySQL Select Queries

Tags: mysql, select

I have two queries to get the count of active and inactive users.

Query 1 (Count Active Users)

```
select COUNT(id) as qty,
       Date(active_on) as active_on_date 
from `activations` 
where `store_id` = 2475 
  and `current_status` = 'active' 
  and `active_on` is not null 
  and (`active_on` between '2021-01-24 14:15:55' and '2021-02-16 14:15:55') 
group by `active_on_date` 
order by `active_on_date` asc
```

Query 2 (Count Inactive Users)

```
select COUNT(id) as qty 
from `activations` 
where `store_id` = 2475 
  and `current_status` = 'inactive' 
  and `active_on` is null
  and `proceed_on` is not null 
  and (`proceed_on` between '2021-01-24 14:15:55' and '2021-02-16 14:15:55') group by Date(proceed_on) 
order by Date(proceed_on) asc
```

Nb: proceed_on and active_on are different date columns.
I want to get this result:

| Qty Active | Qty Unactive | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |

Is it any effective way to produce the result using one query?

This is the example of my table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38458b/1

Comment: @Strawberry Noted, thanks

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT SUM(current_status = 'active') AS qty_active,
       SUM(current_status = 'unactive') AS qty_unactive,
       DATE(active_on) AS active_on_date 
FROM activations
WHERE store_id = 2475 
  AND active_on BETWEEN '2021-01-24 14:15:55' AND '2021-02-16 14:15:55'
GROUP BY active_on_date 
ORDER BY active_on_date ASC
```

PS. It is strange to count while grouping by date but from/till the middle of the day. What kind of magical time is this - `14:15:55`?

Comment: That time is just a random time for testing the query. It can't get the value of inactive, because active_on and proceed_on are 2 different dates. To get inactive value, active_on should be null. I am thinking to use a subquery, but I'm stuck.

Comment: @Evan If so then edit the condition in the SUM() argument accordingly. For example, `SUM(current_status = 'unactive' AND active_on IS NULL) AS qty_unactive`

Comment: But, it already has `AND active_on BETWEEN '2021-01-24 14:15:55' AND '2021-02-16 14:15:55'` filter, and active_on is null already have 0 value.

Comment: @Evan This was an example. Idea. Demonstration that you may use any expression with any level of complexity.